# delphi 2009 accelerators

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

How to remove the Accelerators from TMainMenuActionBar ?

can't seem to find the AutoHotKey = maManual property to change, nor to find any other property that will cause the right effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Assuming the question is about `TActionMainMenuBar`) you would set the `AutoHotKeys` property through the `ActionManager` component that the action bar is linked to (through its `ActionManager` property). Unlike the TMainMenu's AutoHotKeys, this one is a boolean property.

To set the property at design time,

- Select the 'ActionManager' component on the form

  Click the `...` button on the right side of the `ActionBars` property in OI.

  Select your MainMenuBar from the popped up `Editing ActionManager1.ActionBars'` dialog.

  Click the `...` button on the right side of the `Items` property in OI, which will launch the `Editing ActionManager1.Items` dialog

  Do not select any of the items at this time. Instead, set the `AutoHotKeys` property to True or False in OI.

At run time you can do:

```
ActionManager1.ActionBars[0].Items.AutoHotKeys := False;
```

Note that you might need to re-set the Caption of an Item after toggling AutoHotKeys. I.e. 'F&ormat' -> 'Format'.

Comment: Its original, good answers like this (on rare problems like this) that i really want to find or fav whenever i need it again a year later. I hope Stackoverflow search is good, or gets a fav feature.